# redirect() not working in custom Laravel 5 package

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-socialite

Been facing an issue all week and I know it's probably simple but can't seem to figure it out :(

whenever I use in my custom package

```
return redirect('redirectToRoute');
```

all I get is a white screen if I use

```
dd(redirect('redirectToRoute'));
```

I can see the status is a 302
works perfectly fine outside of my package within the app folder but not inside my custom package
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is advisable to add package name in routes when creating custom pakage. like this   Route::controllers([
 'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Comment: Thanks for response mate :) not sure what you mean though??

Comment: I mean When you are working with custom packages add Custom package name in route. for e.g. package route 'auth' =>  'Auth\AuthController'. here before Authcontroller i have add package name.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

I just got the solution.
You have to add ->send()

like

```
return redirect()->to(route('something'))->send();
```

it works